# Bridge-up bridge-down variation of bridge pattern

Tags: design-patterns, bridge

Can somebody explain the difference between "Bridge-up" and "Bridge-down" approach in using "Bridge" pattern? Probably, I just can't get the idea. 
To make it clear, what am I talking about, take a look at [the part of the book with explanation](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=pD2XMZLGUAYC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=bridge%20up%20bridge%20down%20pattern&source=bl&ots=vaeXY8roey&sig=dwwIcTUHs66W9ZvCHheEhLwy2HU&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=g1euUbr7Oc7XPJaFgegC&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=bridge%20up%20bridge%20down%20pattern&f=false)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is maybe not a very good question for StackOverflow, but since I was the technical editor of the book you reference I feel like I ought to try to make an effort here.

First off let's summarize the problem.

We have some code that provides a service -- call this **OriginalService** and we have some code which consumes a service -- call this code **Client**.  We wish to implement the service a second time in such a manner that **Client** can talk to both **OriginalService** and **NewService** with equal facility.

Professor Bishop is drawing a distinction between two scenarios. In the "bridge up" scenario you have an existing **OriginalService** and a **Client** that talks directly to it; in order to add a second service you've got to make an abstraction of the service. In the "bridge down" scenario you know when you are designing the original service that clients are going to need to talk to multiple versions of this service, and design in an abstraction layer from the start.

Consider for example the problem of video drivers. If you have an operating system (client) that knows how to talk to exactly one video card (original service), that operating system is unlikely to be very popular. Instead the OS talks to a *driver*. Each video card manufacturer makes a driver for its supported operating systems, and now the operating system can talk to many drivers. The driver "builds a bridge" between the OS and the video card.

If you start with an operating system that only knows how to talk to one kind of video card and then you retrofit a driver system on top of that, you're in a "bridge up" scenario.

If you realize from day one that you're going to need an abstraction over hardware and start building an architecture based on drivers immediately, you're in a "bridge down" scenario.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, Eric. I thought that "bridge up" and "bridge down" are the variations of bridge pattern. Now I understand that it is a scenario of building the bridge. It just depends on what we have in the beginning: abstraction or implementation.